# php Add to the basket with a given quantity

Tags: php, session, post, cart

I'm trying to make a simple catalog with the addition in the basket and ordering, but I have a problem: all works well while adding the required quantity of product in the shopping cart, but if I want to add another one, then nothing comes out. It simply updates quantity to 1.

Form:

```
<form action="buy.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
    <?php if ($product['quantity'] === 0): ?>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" disabled="true">Not available</button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <inputtype="number" name="productQuantity" value="1">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Add to cart</button>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

buy.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $productId = $_POST['productId'];

    $productQuantity = $_POST['productQuantity'];

    $_SESSION['cart'][$productId] = [
        'quantity' => $productQuantity
    ];
}

header('Location: http://localhost:8000/');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the whole session variable with the new entry. Instead of adding the entry to an array.

Try to use this code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $productId = $_POST['productId'];

    $productQuantity = $_POST['productQuantity'];

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id' => $productId, 'quantity' => $productQuantity);
}

header('Location: http://localhost:8000/');
```

With this code you will have an array with all entries included. I think this is also easier to use later.

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution: $_SESSION['cart'][$productId]['quantity'] += $productQuantity;